# How to solve my problem in Android installed in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: android-studio

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API R, revision 2
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 416
Downloading Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API R, revision 2
Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 416
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install "Google Play services" package?